# Managed Esent - quicker way to read data?

Tags: c#, managed, jet, esent

Using the Managed Esent interface to read data from a table. I am doing this with (pseudo):

```
List<ColumnInfo> columns; //Three columns to be read

using (var table = Table(session,DBID,"tablename",OpenTableGrbit.Readonly))
{
    while (Api.TryMoveNext(session, table))
    {
        foreach (ColumnInfo col in columns)
        {
            string data = GetFormattedColumnData(session,table,col);
        }
    }
}
```

I am interested in data from three columns only, which is around 4,000 rows. However, the table itself is 1,800,000 rows. Hence this approach is very slow to just read the data I want as I need to read all 1,800,000 rows. Is there a quicker way?

Comment: One of the things you should do is use an **index** to **seek** to the rows you are interested in. Once you have those 4,000 unique record keys, you are supposed to then seek the main data 4000 times, to read those 4000 individual rows.

Answer (score 2):

There are many things you can do. Here are a few things off the top of my head:

- Set the minimum cache size `SystemParameters.CacheSizeMin`. The default cache sizing algorithm is a bit conservative sometimes.
- Also set `OpenTableGrbit.Squential` when opening your table. This helps a little bit with prefetching.
- Use `Api.RetrieveColumns` to retrieve the three values at once. This reduces the number of calls/pinvokes you'll do.

-martin